# Controller can't find the view in Yii

Tags: php, yii

I want a view from another module to be rendered and I use path `'//modulename/foldername/viewname'`(without `.php`), but when I run it I get "Controller can't find the view" error. What do I do wrong? It used to work before. My version of Yii is 1.1.15.

EDIT:
These is my urlManager:

```
'urlManager'    => array(
            'class'          => 'yupe\components\urlManager\LangUrlManager',
            'languageInPath' => true,
            'langParam'      => 'language',
            'urlFormat'      => 'path',
            'showScriptName' => false,
            'cacheID'        => 'cache',
            'rules'          => array(
)
```

But how can it be related to my problem? Doesn't urlManager has nothing to do with view aliases?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

give it the full path to that file:

```
$this->render('application.modules.modulename.foldername.viewname' , $arrayData);
```

Comment: did you find what you've been looking for?

Comment: Why do I need to write physical address? I need to know why that old way that worked before doesn't work now.

Comment: this type of addressing will always work, if you want to know why the old one don't work, you have to check what at context you where trying to call that view, by default the short form is for the folder of the controller or the module that you are calling render

Comment: so in a controller context, the short form is supposed to point to a controller view file, can't address to module from controller