# a route doesnt work (yii)

Tags: yii, routes

Hy stackoverflow !
I'm trying to make a form into an external page with Yii 1.1.14 (this is an old site).

I've made a directory into my views call `signinPartners` and into this one, a php file call `signin`.

I have also created a controller :

```
class SigninPartnerController extends Controller
{
    public function actionSignin(){
        $this->render('/signin');
    }
}
```

He renders the route `/signin` defined in my config by :

```
return array(
    '' => 'index',
    'signin' => 'signinPartners/signin',
);
```

but when I try the URL `http://mylocalserver/signin` the site send back `Error 404 Unable to resolve the request « signin-partners/signin ».`.

This is really disturbing because there are other URL's on my website and they work the same way without throwing an error 404. I don't know what I missed... Can somebody help ?

my urlManager :

```
'urlManager'=>array(
    'urlFormat'=>'path',
    'showScriptName' => false, // do not display index.php in the url
    'urlSuffix' => '/',
    'rules' => $routesRules, //this variable contains the array defined above
),
```

I have also check my runtime :

```
2018/01/17 11:12:16 [error] [exception.CHttpException.404] exception 'CHttpException' with message 'Impossible de résoudre la requête « signinPartners/signin ».' in D:\Windows\Windows\CommonFiles\wamp64\www\MoovTime-Conso\library\Yii\web\CWebApplication.php:286
Stack trace:
#0 D:\Windows\Windows\CommonFiles\wamp64\www\MoovTime-Conso\library\Yii\web\CWebApplication.php(141): CWebApplication->runController('signinPartners...')
#1 D:\Windows\Windows\CommonFiles\wamp64\www\MoovTime-Conso\library\Yii\base\CApplication.php(183): CWebApplication->processRequest()
#2 D:\Windows\Windows\CommonFiles\wamp64\www\MoovTime-Conso\public\frontend\index.php(36): CApplication->run()
#3 {main}
REQUEST_URI=/signin
---
```

(the exception message is in french and means `Unable to resolve the request « signin-partners/signin »`)

Ok, big update, i've tried to play with `routes.php` and I realized that the name of my controller doesn't match with `signinPartners`. So, I update the routes rules with :

```
return array(
    '' => 'index',
    'signin' => 'signinPartner/signin',
);
```

And now, we have a new error : `Controller can't find the view « /signin ».`.
There is the post [Controller can't find the view in Yii](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25112374/controller-cant-find-the-view-in-yii) which can anwser this question !

**ANSWERED**

Comment: which version of yii you are using?

Comment: Yii 1.1.14 (i update the post)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in my case was the action, the directory name in my view that contains the page and the route rule.

first, I update the route rule from :

```
return array(
    '' => 'index',
    'signin' => 'signinPartners/signin',
);
```

to :

```
return array(
    '' => 'index',
    'signin' => 'signinPartner/signin', // controlerName/actionName
);
```

The controller name was wrong.

In a second time, to match with the name of the controller, I simply renamed the directory in `views` calls `signinPartners` to `signinPartner` (only for readability).

Finally I update the action `actionSignin` that was :

```
public function actionSignin(){
    $this->render('/signin');
}
```

For :

```
public function actionSignin(){
    $this->render('/signinPartner/signin');
}
```

Where I change the path with the new directory name.

Answer (score 0):

try adding a `-` in signinPartners.

```
'signin-partners/signin'
```

Comment: this doesn't work, I rename the route and the directory and there is the same error with the new name